# Bar magnets side by side, opposite polarity, repulsion at null point?

Tags: electromagnetism

Bar magnets side by side with opposite polarity will attract and attach to one another if they get close enough to one another. Besides that strong attractive force, is there also a weaker repulsive force at the null point in the image below, where magnetic flux around sides of magnets is in opposite direction?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What makes two magnets attract/repel each other is the fact that north poles "like" to have field lines going outward and south poles "like" to have them going inwards. When you place a north pole and south pole close, their magnetic fields add constructively, this makes them attract each other. With two bar magnets side by side that have opposite polarity, notice that you can change the lines at the center to make the lines go out of the north poles and into the south poles, so they will attract in the middle too.

[image]